# Sharepoint 2010 Lists, is value specific formatting of columns or rows possible?

Tags: list, css

I would like to format columns or rows that contain certain values, without any client side javascript hacks. I'm looking for an OOB solution.

For example - if 1 column in my list being of type boolean (yes/no) contains a no valid - I would like to change the background color of the row.

Or if a column contains a text field, and let's say with the value of "Not updated" - I would like to change the font in that column to #ff0000;

Last example would be to check a date range, and if a column in the list (date column) has a value that meets certain criteria then so some or other styling to the row or a specific column.

Is any of this possible?

Comment: Are you willing to consider a 3rd party solution, or making your own Custom Field Type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Lori says, because this is XSL-based you have several options. I can think of three ways to get your XSL in place off the top of my head:

1. Edit in SharePoint Designer 2010 and do some 'conditional formatting'. This will in effect embed the XSL in the web part.
2. Put your XSL in a separate file and use the XSL Link property to add it to the web part. One advantage of this is that it can be re-used across several web parts. I've blogged on this [XLV Override Technique](http://www.glynblogs.com/2011/04/overriding-the-presentation-of-an-xslt-list-view-web-part.html) previously, including an example based on a out of the box tasks list.
3. Deploy some XSL to the file system, making use of the extensibility of the fldtypes_*.xsl technique - similar to as if making a completely custom field type. This is a useful approach if you'd like your formatting to be applied universally without having to worry about configuring specific web parts - and can even be targeted at specific columns and/ or lists.

HTH

Comment: +1 for the list of options and decent blog post, but look, have you actually tried the 3rd option yourself (with fldtypes_*.xsl)? It doesn't work for me and I heard from my fellows about the same issue.

Comment: Hi Omlin - yes I've tried option 3. I've done this to target a specific column on a list by targeting the column name and the list ID.

Answer (score 5):

Since list views in SharePoint 2010 are XSL list views, you can apply conditional formatting to them through SharePoint Designer, just like you can with Data View Web Parts.